# How to stop Content-Encoding gzip properties of WebDav Response on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, webdav

When request to a file in Ubuntu Server WebDav, it will response a header included Content-Encoding. How can I disable it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to send the request header field below:

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

But *why* do you want to disable it?